# ¿Qué significa "{...props}"en la implementacion de un componente?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Buen dia a todos,
Estoy aprendiendo react, encontré un código y estaba leyéndolo y me percate de que utiliza las líneas {...props} en la implementación de un componente, algo así:

```
...
return(
<titulo 
    valor="titulo 1" 
    visible={isVIsible} 
    {...props}/>
)
```

He tratado de buscar por internet pero no he encontrado nada. Según mi lógica, le estaría pasando también los props de padre al hijo, pero no estoy seguro de ello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sintáxis de propagación JSX

Hay diseños en los cuales, el `componente padre` está configurado con una cantidad considerable de `propiedades`, las cuales se deben pasar a un `componente hijo`:

```
//pseudicódigo n propiedades parent component
const props = {
propA:"value A",
propB:"value B",
propC:"value C",
...
propN:"prop N"
}
```

Ahora, en vez de pasar cada una de las propiedades al `child component`, por ejemplo:

```
<ChildComp propA={"value A"} propB={"value B"} ... propN={"value N"} />
```

Se puede usar la `sintáxis de propagación JSX`:

```
<ChildComp {...props} />
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.